# Beta Newsletters

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, beta-phase, newsletter

I've just learned that there are newsletters. Woah! These seem like a great idea in order to keep traffic flowing to our, relatively, new [Raspberry Pi community](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). What do we need to do to get this started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing - it should happen automatically.

Of course, it *isn't* happening automatically right now, so... It has been manually enabled. For the record, these sites did not have newsletters, but now do:

https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

https://chess.stackexchange.com/

http://libraries.stackexchange.com/

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

https://russian.stackexchange.com/

https://islam.stackexchange.com/

...In the future, this will happen automatically after a site enters public beta.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if it seems I'm being pushy. I'm just excited trying to get more people to our site and I feel like a newsletter would definitely help us considering our userbase is people who are new to the Raspberry Pi and Linux important.

Comment: Totally understandable - and if you hadn't said anything, they would've been unavailable for six other sites as well, so hey - thanks!